# Opening Microsoft Onenote app within a separate app via button click

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, onenote, startapp

I am working with a cordova app that will allow the user to open the Microsoft Onenote app on their phone if it is already installed. I am not looking for an in-app browser to appear on screen but the Onenote app itself.

I am currently using the [startapp](https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp) plugin
I have tried to get the pathing so it could open at any page in the app just to see if it will work so I used this code:

> "component":["com.microsoft.office.onenote","com.microsoft.office.onenote.ui.ONMOtherSettingsActivity"]

This code does not work, however the below code relating to the Microsoft Outlook app using the same method works:

> "component":
>   ["com.microsoft.office.outlook", "com.microsoft.office.outlook.MainActivity"]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with cordova or startapp, but if you want to open onenote from a mobile device, you'll need a the URL to OneNote (which is "onenote://...") - the MSDN post below talks about this.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn575433.aspx